# Laravel "davibennun/laravel-push-notification"

Tags: php, laravel, push-notification

I am using davibennun/laravel-push-notification in laravel framework for push notification, it worked well when sending notification to single device id but when using like

```
$devices = PushNotification::DeviceCollection(array(
  PushNotification::Device('token', array('badge' => 5)),
  PushNotification::Device('token1', array('badge' => 1)),
  PushNotification::Device('token2')
));
```

it shows following error:

```
Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException (E_ERROR) Call to a member function getTokens() on a non-object
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you the stacktrace of the error? The exception said, that the lib will call a function on an object, which isnt an object.